# Linker : how to place a block of data at a specific address boundary

Tags: gcc, linker, alignment, mmu

This may be an easy question but I am a beginner with the linker file of GNU GCC (codesourcery arm-none-eabi ver 4.5.2).

I have to initialize the Mmu in a ARM7 processor and in datasheet, it is said that the Mmu page table must be located at a 16kbyte (2^14) boundary.

For now I have come with this solution, but I'm almost certain that this is not the more efficient one!

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
 . = 0x0;
 .text : {_stext = .;
*startall.o (.text)
. = 0x4000;
*MmuSdram0.o (.text)
*(.text)
_etext = .;}
 .data : {_sdata = .;
*(.data) 
_edata = .;}
 .bss : {_sbss = .;
*(.bss) 
_ebss = .;}
}
```

startall.o is an assembly file containing processor initialisation.
Next line, I set the address to 0x4000 (boundary of 2^14).
MmuSdram0.o is containing the Mmu page table.
Then follow the rest of the firmware.
Obviously, this solution give me a gap between the end of startall and 0x4000, which i a waste of memory space(I don't like waste ;-)

What I would do instead is to put the pagetable after the *(.text) but I don't know how to do something like :
*(.text) *"except"* MmuSdram0.o
And I prefer to let the linker place the page table at the next available 2^14 boundary instead of fixing the address myself. I checked in the linker documentation, found ALIGN command, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly or if this even the command that fit my need...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm surprised nobody answered this question, is it a not so easy question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, place the `__attribute__ (( aligned(16*1024) ))` before the semicolon ';' of your mmu table declaration

Comment: the disadvantage of this way, IMHO, is gcc will reserve all 16 KBytes for your mmu table. That says if your mmu table's size is not 16 Kbytes, you will waste the rest. In fact, I am struggling to find a solution without modifying linker script.

Comment: To be more precise, the table is defined in a assembly file, so I put a .align 14 before defining my table and it worked.